# Coldfusion and SQL Server database security

Tags: security, sql-server-2005

I have an account on a coldfusion/SQL Server shared server hosting service and have been targeted by what I believe to be a SQL injection attack. I have a absolute path to a javascript file in nearly every field of every table. It seems the script hides majority of the text and features on every page it is on. I'm lucky enough to be able to restore the database to a reasonable point, but I need to prevent this from happening again. Is there anything else I can do besides `<cfqueryparam></cfqueryparam>` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout `<cfqueryparams>` tag: http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/coldfusion/7/htmldocs/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=ColdFusion_Documentation&file=part_cfm.htm

This is how to clean up user-submitted input for SQL queries.

Answer (score 1):

The recommended solution is to review ALL your code and make sure that you don't build your sql statements via string concatenation. Instead, use parametrized queries and sanitize user input. That's recommended for any kind of database you use.

[Take a look at this post.](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3834501/Parameterized-Queries.htm)

**EDIT -  Providing C# Example as requested:**

```
string sql = "insert into table_a (cola,colb,colc) values (@value_a,@value_v,@value_c)";

using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("ConnectionString"))
{
    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql,conn);
    command.CommandType = Commandtype.Text;
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value_a",txtFieldAFromForm.Text);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value_b",txtFieldBFromForm.Text);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value_c",txtFieldCFromForm.Text);
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: "Instead, use parametrized queries and sanitize user input." By parametrized queries do you mean stored procedures?  And Sanitize user input should be taken care of with <cfqueryparam></cfqueryparam>, correct?

Comment: @d.lanza38 no, you can build parametrized queries w/o using stored procedures. Apparently in ColdFusion that's done via `<cfqueryparam>` (see here:http://www.alocurto.com/blog4.php/ColdFusion/sql-injection-in-cold-fusion). I can provide a C# example of an inline SQL Statement that uses parameters but I don't know if you code in C# or you'll find it useful. Let me know.

Comment: I've done a little c# in the past, I should be able to understand it.  I would like to see how you do it in c#.  However I do believe all of the sql statements I have on this database are using <cfqueryparam> already.  If that is the equivalent then I don't need you to post it.  Thank you.

Comment: @d.lanza38 the fact that you ended up with extraneous data in your table is an indication that your code is obviously vulnerable. The link I posted plus some other links I found on the internet all mentioned that using `<cfqueryparam>` is enough to guard against SQL Injection so you either didn't inspect all your code or ColdFusion has a **major** security hole. I will post my C# example next.